# Plural of the term "South African" when referring to more than 1 person

Tags: south-african-english

I'm wondering about the plural of the term "South African" when used in context:

There are two *South African* people standing there.
My wife and I are *South African* here in Argentina.

The first one sounds more correct as: **South African**
The second one sounds more correct as: South African**s** or is it South African **'s**

Just wondering about the correct spelling/wording.

Comment: The "singular" version is an *adjectival* usage, which would be unlikely in your specific context. Consider a syntactically similar form with a more straightforward adjective: *We are **happy** here in Argentina*. That could either mean *We [the people of Argentina] are happy* OR something along the lines of *We used to be somewhere else [where by implication we weren't happy], but now we've come to Argentina we are happy*. Since the state of "being South African" can't normally change, it can't be used with that second sense (and the first interpretation would be nonsensical, obviously).

Comment: ...your uncertainty regarding the possibility of possessive ***South African's*** implies this question belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in your first sentence, **South African** is an adjective, while it's a noun in your second one. To answer your question, the correct term would be **South Africans**. I don't know where you got the notion that an *'s* would be included.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, i never thought that they are different parts of speech. I was thinking of them both as simple plurals, and getting my brain in a knot!